# Lex only detects symbols when there is whitespace between them

Tags: regex, lex

I want Lex, when given an input of "foo+1", to first return the identifier "foo", then the character '+', and then the integer 1. This works if I lex "foo + 1", but for some reason with the grammar I have, it doesn't work if I omit the spaces, and it skips over the '+', just returning "foo" and then 1. I can't figure out why. Is there anything here that seems problematic?

```
%{
#include "expression.h"
#include "picoScanner.h"
static int block_comment_num = 0;
static char to_char(char *str);
int yylineno = 0;
%}

%option nodefault yyclass="FlexScanner" noyywrap c++


%x LINE_COMMENT
%x BLOCK_COMMENT

%%

Any                     { return pico::BisonParser::token::ANY; }
Int                     { return pico::BisonParser::token::INT; }
Float                   { return pico::BisonParser::token::FLOAT; }
Char                    { return pico::BisonParser::token::CHAR; }
List                    { return pico::BisonParser::token::LIST; }
Array                   { return pico::BisonParser::token::ARRAY; }
Table                   { return pico::BisonParser::token::TABLE; }
alg                     { return pico::BisonParser::token::ALG; }
if                      { return pico::BisonParser::token::IF; }
then                    { return pico::BisonParser::token::THEN; }
else                    { return pico::BisonParser::token::ELSE; }
is                      { return pico::BisonParser::token::IS; }
or                      { return pico::BisonParser::token::OR; }
and                     { return pico::BisonParser::token::AND; }
not                     { return pico::BisonParser::token::NOT; }
when                    { return pico::BisonParser::token::WHEN; }
[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*      { yylval->strval = new std::string(yytext); 
                          return pico::BisonParser::token::TYPENAME; }
[a-z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*     { printf("saw '%s'\n", yytext); yylval->strval = new std::string(yytext); 
                          return pico::BisonParser::token::ID; }
"=="                    { return pico::BisonParser::token::EQ; }
"<="                    { return pico::BisonParser::token::LEQ; }
">="                    { return pico::BisonParser::token::GEQ; }
"!="                    { return pico::BisonParser::token::NEQ; }
"->"                    { return pico::BisonParser::token::RETURN; }
[\+\-\*/%]              { return yytext[0]; }

[-+]?[0-9]+             { yylval->ival = atoi(yytext); 
                          return pico::BisonParser::token::INT_LITERAL; }
([0-9]+|([0-9]*\.[0-9]+)([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?)  { yylval->fval = atof(yytext); 
                                               return pico::BisonParser::token::FLOAT_LITERAL; }
\"(\\.|[^\\"])*\"       { yylval->strval = new std::string(strndup(yytext+1, strlen(yytext) - 2)); 
                          return pico::BisonParser::token::STRING_LITERAL; }
\'(\\.|[^\\'])*\'       { yylval->cval = to_char(yytext+1); 
                          return pico::BisonParser::token::CHAR_LITERAL; }
[ \t\r]+                { /* ignore */ }
\n                      { yylineno++;  }
.                       { printf("~~~~~~~~~~munched %s\n", yytext); return yytext[0]; }

%%

static char to_char(char *str) {
   if (strlen(str) <= 1) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Error: empty character constant (line %d)\n", yylineno);
      exit(1);
   } else if (str[0] != '\\') {
      return str[0];
   } else {
      if (strlen(str) == 1) {
         fprintf(stderr, "Error: somehow we got a single slash character\n");
         exit(1);
      }
      switch (str[1]) {
         case 'n': return '\n';
         case 'r': return '\r';
         case 't': return '\t';
         case 'a': return '\a';
         case 'b': return '\b';
         case 'f': return '\f';
         case 'v': return '\v';
         case '\'': return '\'';
         case '"': return '"';
         case '\\': return '\\';
         case '?': return '\?';
         case 'x':
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: unicode not yet supported (line %d)\n", yylineno);
            exit(1);
         default:
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: unrecognized escape sequence '\\%c' (line %d)\n", 
                                                                     str[1], yylineno);
            exit(1);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not familair with lex, but I'm pretty sure the following causes the error:

```
[-+]?[0-9]+             { yylval->ival = atoi(yytext); 
                      return pico::BisonParser::token::INT_LITERAL; }
```

`foo` is parsed as an identifier, but then "+0" is parsed as an `int` literal (due to the `atoi` conversion, the sign is discarded).

It is probably a good idea to only consider unsigned numeric literals at a *lexer* level, and handle signs at the level of the parser (treating the `+` and `-` tokens differently depending on their context).
Not only does this resolve the ambiguity, but it also enables you to "correctly" (in the sense that these are legal in C, C++, Java etc.) parse integer literals such as `- 5` instead of `-5`.

Moreover: are the escaping backslashs in the arithmetic operator rule really necessary? Afaik, the only characters with special meaning inside a character class are `-`, `^`, and `]` (but I might be wrong).

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like it's matching `foo+1` as `foo` and `+1` (an `INT_LITERAL`). See related thread: [Is it possible to set priorities for rules to avoid the "longest-earliest" matching pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8379299/is-it-possible-to-set-priorities-for-rules-to-avoid-the-longest-earliest-match)

You could add an explicit rule to match `+` as a token, otherwise it sounds like Lex is going to take the longest match it can (`+1` is longer than `+`).